# How can I set the same set of environment variables for multiple upstart daemons?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, environment-variables, upstart

I have a bunch of job/daemon configuration files, say:

```
/etc/init/service1.conf
/etc/init/service2.conf
/etc/init/service3.conf
```

Most of those jobs are quite similar, and the files are of a format like:

```
description "Some service"

...
env NAME1=VALUE1
env NAME2=VALUE2
env NAME3=VALUE3
...

exec something
```

The `env` variable section is the same across all files. Is there an easy way to avoid having to repeat the variables in all the files, while also not setting them system-wide (they should only be visible to the jobs)? Something like a `#include "env_config.txt"` that I can replace the `env` section in the configs with?

Comment: You could do that with systemd. But Ubuntu was very late adopting it, and so you'll need to be on 16.04 LTS or later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `set -a` to export all the varibles followed by sourcing `.` the file

```
set -a 
. /path/to/envvars
```